# How to upload a saved file from google colab to a site such as kaggle or github?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, bigdata, google, colab

We are able to load a file from a site such as kaggle and git hub to google collab, we apply the below code to download from other sites into google colab:

> ```
> !wget nlp.stanford.edu/data/glove.6B.zip
> ```

but I am very curious to know if I am able to upload a saved file (such as an output from google colab) to kaggle or github with a command like above?

Comment: Again you can, save your model in your drive and make a connection after making the link public.

Comment: Take a look at the answers [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/colab).

Comment: Also see OP’s questions [How to upload a file from Google Colab to GitHub or Kaggle?](//askubuntu.com/q/1068819/175814) and [How to upload a data set from a command-line (such as Google Collaboratory) into Kaggle?](//askubuntu.com/q/1090489/175814) and their answers over at Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your directory `/miryam/myproject`:

```
git init .    
git add myfile    
git commit -m "First commit"    
git remote add origin remote https://github.com/yours_project    
git push origin master
```